# WordPress: Remove Featured Image From Specific Page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I was able to remove the featured image metabox from custom post types of pages. Below is what I used:

```
add_action('do_meta_boxes', 'remove_thumbnail_box');
function remove_thumbnail_box() {
  remove_meta_box( 'postimagediv','page','side' );
}
```

However, what I really want to do is to only apply this to a specific page template. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, I found a solution.

```
$post_id = $_GET['post'] ? $_GET['post'] : $_POST['post_ID'] ;
$template_file = get_post_meta($post_id,'_wp_page_template',TRUE);
if ($template_file === 'page-template-name.php') {
  add_action('do_meta_boxes', 'remove_thumbnail_box');
  function remove_thumbnail_box() {
    remove_meta_box( 'postimagediv','page','side' );
  }
}
```

If there's a better solution... please don't hesitate to post.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else looking to remove featured image support programatically (the comments should be self explanatory):

```
/**
*   Removes the featured image metabox from specific pages (by ID)
*   @note: populate the $excluded_page_ids_array array with page IDs
*/
function eh_remove_featured_image_metabox_from_specific_pages() {
    // populate with page IDs to exclude featured image metabox from
    $excluded_page_ids_array = array( 38, 29 );
    // store the current post ID
    $post_id = $_GET['post'] ? $_GET['post'] : $_POST['post_ID'];
    // check if the current page is in our excluded array
    if( in_array( $post_id, $excluded_page_ids_array ) ) {
        // remove featured image metabox
        remove_meta_box( 'postimagediv','page','side' );
    }
}
add_action( 'do_meta_boxes', 'remove_featured_image_metabox_from_specific_pages' );
```

After adjusting the array of pages to exclude, you'll want to add this snippet to your themes functions.php file.

Alternatively, you can remove the featured image from *all* pages, except specified ones - where the featured image metabox will remain.

```
/**
*   Removes the featured image metabox from all pages except specified ones
*   @note: populate the $page_ids array with page IDs
*/
function eh_remove_featured_images_metabox_from_all_pages_except_specified() {
    // populate with page IDs to keep the featured image metabox on
    $page_ids = array( 25, 31 );
    $post_id = $_GET['post'] ? $_GET['post'] : $_POST['post_ID'];
    if( ! in_array( $post_id, $page_ids ) ) {
        // remove featured image metabox
        remove_meta_box( 'postimagediv','page','side' );
    }
}
add_action( 'do_meta_boxes', 'eh_remove_featured_images_metabox_from_all_pages_except_specified' );
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution. By editing the `page.php`

If your feature Image div Looks like below for example

```
<div class="thumbnail">
  <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $size, $attr ); ?> 
</div>
```

you can use

if (is_page( array( 42, 'about-me', 'Contact' ) );
// Returns true when the Pages displayed is either post ID :42, or post_name_slug "about-me", or post_title "Contact".

```
<?php
if (is_page( array( 42, 'about-me', 'Contact' ) ) ) {
    ?>
<div class="thumbnail" style="display:none;">
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $size, $attr ); ?> 
</div>
<?php
}else{
?>
<div class="thumbnail">
 <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $size, $attr ); ?> 
</div>
<?php}?>
```

Comment: hiding is something different than removing, which is what the OP asked.